# Load a page in the same window via javascript

Tags: javascript, load, html

How do you load a page in the same window via javascript?

Answer (score 12):

You set the location property of the window:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.guffa.com/';
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in mobile Safari on IOS. window.open (...) works. Any ideas?

Comment: Im trying with window.open but not having much success